# Reading STDOUT of subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

Hello I want to read output of command which gives progress bar like output as show below

```
10% |****                       | 3:56 ETA
```

I tried with following code

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen("command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    split = line.rstrip()
    print line
    print "\n"
print "Done"
```

This code reads output after completion of progress bar to 100%, but I want to read it at intermediate.
Can any one help?

Comment: No its scalpel, file recovery tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `readline()` but the progress bar is all printed on one line, so `readline()` waits until the progress bar has been fully printed, as that is when a line break occurs. Try `read(1)` to get a character at a time.

Comment: Hello thanks it working, but if I want to omit starting version lines that is printed by subprocess, how will I do that?